# Parsing text file to objects in an array in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am new to javaScript, suppose I have a text file (test.txt) contains hundreds of lines of code and  have the following format:

```
4 6
5 7
4 7
2 6
...
```

The first num in each line is source and second num is target. Right now I want to parse into the javaScript objects like this:

```
var links = [
{source: '4', target: '6'},
{source: '5', target: '7'},
{source: '4', target: '7'},
{source: '2', target: '6'}];
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume here that you already have the contents of your file in a string named `filecontent` (doing that is already a nontrivial thing, depending on where your javascript resides). Then here is a straight-forward implementation :

```
var lines = filecontent.split('\n');//puts the lines in an array
var links = [];
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i){
    var values = lines[i].split(' ');//transforms "4 6" into ["4", "6"]
    links[i] = {source : values[0], target : values[1]};
    //then into the format you wanted !
}
```